# EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' no tiene ninguna clave definida

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tengo un problema con un proyecto ASP MVC con identity, al modificar el ID a int todo es correcto me genera la columna tipo int, pero al intentar cambiar los nombres de las columnas de las tablas me genera un error al ejecutar el proyecto. 
He intentado varias soluciones que he encontrado pero sigo sin poder solucionarlo, alguna idea?

El error es:

> PortalPrueba1.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType
>   'IdentityUserLogin' no tiene ninguna clave definida. Defina la clave
>   para este EntityType.
>
> PortalPrueba1.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole'
>   no tiene ninguna clave definida. Defina la clave para este EntityType.
>
> IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' se basa
>   en el tipo 'IdentityUserLogin' que no tiene claves definidas.
>
> IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' se basa
>   en el tipo 'IdentityUserRole' que no tiene claves definidas.

Mi codigo en identityModels es el siguiente:

```
namespace PortalPrueba1.Models
{

    public class CustomUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
    public class CustomUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
    public class CustomUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }

    public class CustomRole : IdentityRole<int, CustomUserRole>
    {
        public CustomRole() { }
        public CustomRole(string name) { Name = name; }
    }

    public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int,
        CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
    {
        public CustomUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }
    }

    public class CustomRoleStore : RoleStore<CustomRole, int, CustomUserRole>
    {
        public CustomRoleStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }
    }


    // Para agregar datos de perfil del usuario, agregue más propiedades a su clase ApplicationUser. Visite https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 para obtener más información.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole,
    CustomUserClaim>
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(
    UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in
            // CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType 
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(
                this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here 
            return userIdentity;
        }

        public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole,
         int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
        {
            public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
            {
            }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                //throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

                modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Po_Users");
                modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Po_Users");
                modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Po_Roles");
                modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("Po_UserRoles");
                modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("Po_UserClaims");
                modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("Po_UserLogins");

            }

            public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
            {
                return new ApplicationDbContext();
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Hola ya encontré la solución y es que estaba mandando a llamar el modelo de identity y las cambie por las clases "Custom..." que yo había declarado de manera que quedara así:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

                modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Po_Users");
                modelBuilder.Entity<CustomRole>().ToTable("Po_Roles");
                modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserRole>().ToTable("Po_UserRoles");
                modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserClaim>().ToTable("Po_UserClaims");
                modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserLogin>().ToTable("Po_UserLogins");
}
```